# DHT11 is returning nonsensical values

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to get humidity and temperature readings (eventually to trigger a misting system), but the values keep returning as 0C and 0%humidity (in general).  Originally, I was using an am2320 sensor and using the analog pins.  Here, I used the following code:

```
#include "dht.h"
#define dht_apin A2 // Analog Pin sensor is connected to
#define MIST 7
#define LIGHT 2


dht DHT;

void setup(){
 pinMode(MIST, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(LIGHT, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);//Delay to let system boot
  Serial.println("DHT11 Humidity & temperature Sensor\n\n");
  delay(1000);//Wait before accessing Sensor

}//end "setup()"

void loop(){
  //Start of Program 

    DHT.read11(dht_apin);

    Serial.print("Current humidity = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print("%  ");
    Serial.print("temperature = ");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature); 
    Serial.println("C  ");

    delay(5000);     //Wait 5 seconds before accessing sensor again.


  }

  //Fastest should be once every two seconds.

// end loop() 
}
```

Thinking the sensor may have not been working, I tried using a different sensor (DHT11), and following the tutorials got the same result using this code:

```
#include <dht11.h>
#define DHT11PIN 4

dht11 DHT11;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println();

  int chk = DHT11.read(DHT11PIN);

  Serial.print("Humidity (%): ");
  Serial.println((float)DHT11.humidity, 2);

  Serial.print("Temperature (C): ");
  Serial.println((float)DHT11.temperature, 2);

  delay(2000);

}
// end loop()
```

The Arduino is being powered by a wall wart and is also connected to my computer via USB (I read that sometimes the USB doesn't supply enough power).  The weird part is that for about 1 minute I got reasonable results (humidity ~50%, temp 22C).  Then, I tried adding an if loop to turn on an LED if the humidity dropped below 60% (thinking I could use the same code to operate a relay to turn on a misting system).  The LED lit up, but the readout went back to the 0%humidity and 0C.  I have since deleted this loop but cannot seem to get reasonable measurements.  If I change the signal pin, I sometimes get a new readout 255% humidity and 255C, but I haven't been able to repeat this reliably.

For the wiring:  S to pin, + to 5V, - to GND

Note:  I have tried every analog pin and "regular" pin, so the code may designate something that is different in my picture.  When testing, I have triple checked that the signal pin in the code is correct for my wiring configuration.  I've also tried with a different Arduino with the same result.  I'm pretty new at this, but the code is pretty much copy-paste and there are only 3 wires.  I've read that there are many DHT libraries, so I'm thinking my issue has something to do with that, but I have no clue how to judge the appropriateness of a library for my application.

[image: Order of pins = S, +, -]
[image: My wiring][[[[[[[[[[[[p

Comment: Does your DHT11 board has a pull up resistor on it? The Data pin requires a pull-up resistor (4.7k would be okay) to 5V.

Comment: Have you tried a different library, to rule out hardware issues?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line of code in the setup() function:

```
    dht.begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect the sensor as in this diagramm (including a 10k resistor!):
[image: DHT sensor to UNO]

Watch the empty connector opposite to your breadboard plug-in
and use the following test sketch with [this library](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library):

```
// Example testing sketch for DHT humidity/temperature sensor

#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 4     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor

#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11

// Connect pin 1 (on the left) of the sensor to +5V
// NOTE: If using a board with 3.3V logic like an Arduino Due connect pin 1 to 3.3V instead of 5V!
// Connect pin 2 of the sensor to whatever your DHTPIN is
// Connect pin 4 (on the right) of the sensor to GROUND
// Connect a 10K resistor from pin 2 (data) to pin 1 (power) of the sensor

// Initialize DHT sensor.
// Note that older versions of this library took an optional third parameter to
// tweak the timings for faster processors.  This parameter is no longer needed
// as the current DHT reading algorithm adjusts itself to work on faster procs.
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(F("DHTxx test!"));

  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Wait a few seconds between measurements.
  delay(2000);

  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

  // Compute heat index in Fahrenheit (the default)
  float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);
  // Compute heat index in Celsius (isFahreheit = false)
  float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);

  Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(F("%  Temperature: "));
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(F("°C "));
  Serial.print(f);
  Serial.print(F("°F  Heat index: "));
  Serial.print(hic);
  Serial.print(F("°C "));
  Serial.print(hif);
  Serial.println(F("°F"));
}
```

Comment: 2 issues:  1.) The code is giving an "error compiling for board Arduino" (full error message at bottom)  2.) I ony have 3 pins to connect, not four.  Should I try a resistor on the signal pin?   
  DataSheet https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/29/vma311_a4v01.pdf       Full error code

Comment: In file included from LIBRARY LOCATION/DHT_sensor_library-1.3.8/DHT_U.cpp:15:0:
LIBRARY LOCATION/DHT_U.h:36:10: fatal error: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

Comment: @sumbody32point5 do you see any resistor on the sensor's breakout board? If no, then add one between signal and Vcc.

Comment: You need the additiona llib installed its asking for - read the error message: Adafruit_Sensor.h: No such file or directory Add the Adafruit_Sensor lib Install it with IDE via lib manager

Comment: @Codebreaker007 Sorry that was dumb of me - got the library.  The output is now "DHTxx test!    Failed to read from DHT sensor!" There is a resistor on the breakout board, so I don't think that is the issue.  Just to be sure, I measured the resistance berween VCC and data line and got about 10Kohms.  I'm using pin 4 as in your code and tried on other pins as well. I got one reading where the output was "Read from DHT sensor," (one single line) but then it went back to "Failed to read from DHT sensor."  Is there a way to use a multimeter to verify eveything is working?

Comment: also I measured 0.13mA in the signal wire so I would think that meant that data was being sent

Comment: If your sensor is soldered onto a pcb it might be a cold solder blob or a non connecting pin on the breadboard. You could try to directly hold the signal wire to the sensor and test. If that works check the soldering or pin connections. A defect sensor is the least possible solution.

Comment: I think that might be it - I couldn't get a real reading, but I the output changed from "failed to read DHT sensor" to "DHTxx test!" but then went back to the original output.  The sensors are pretty cheap - I might get a second one, try the same configuration, and if it works try my hand at resoldering the original (I'm assuming I will probably mess it up).  I really appreciate your help and patience @codebreaker.